# Socket.io does not send data between node.js and HTML script with a radio button

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to communicate node.js and a HTML script with socket.io. I'm trying that when i choose some value with a radio button, socket.io sends this value to node.js and then, return to the console. My problem is that socket.io doesn't send anything. I know it doesn't enter the socket function because i write an alarm in html if it enters, and nothing. 
Node.js code is this:

```js
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var socketIO = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendfile("./toggle?.html");
});
 
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socketIO.listen(server, {log: false});
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    
    socket.on("sendVar", function(value){
   
   console.log(value)
     
    });
});

server.listen(5000);
```

And the HTML script is this:

```html
 <html> 
<input type="radio" name="group1" value=1> ON<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value=0 checked> OFF<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Button" VALUE="Proceed" onClick="showBoxes(this.form)">

<script>
var radios = document.getElementsByName('group1');
function showBoxes(frm){
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        
        var x=radios[i].value;
           alert(radios[i].value)
  
  //Send the value of the radio button      
  var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000"); //client connection
  socket.on("connect", function(){ 
         alert("connected!")
         socket.emit("sendVar", x);

        });

        
        break;
    }
}

}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Conceptually, a webSocket is most useful when you want a continuously connected client/server.  If you just want to send some data to a client upon a radio button change, you are probably better off to use a simple ajax call rather than make a one-time use websocket connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a specific need to have this web socket open? currently what you have an AJAX call would be more suited. you can handle this with the normal request, response method using express.

You can use a simple express get handler:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

or you can use the router:

```
var app = express();

app.route('/events')
.all(function(req, res, next) {
  // runs for all HTTP verbs first
  // think of it as route specific middleware!
})
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(...);
})
.post(function(req, res, next) {
  // maybe add a new event...
})
```

each solution would be more suited that a socket.

source: http://expressjs.com/api.html